# Excel Formula, To Calcuate a maximum Weight based off a desired minimum profit (GP%)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

So I am working on a spreadsheet for a Butchery I manage and have run into a problem.

First off back story: We do $20 packs for certain bulk products that have a min/max weight range.

The Goal is to be able to put in this spreadsheet the desired minimum GP% and from that get a maximum weight based off that minimum profit margin.

For example a Beef Steak that Costs $17.50 p/kilo Would be minimum of 680g (at a GP% of 30.30%) and a maximum weight of 790g (at a GP% of 20.50%)

I have been 'googling' all day, and banging my head on my desk (as well as experimenting with different formula's) I am starting to think I may have to resort to programming a macro to perform this but I would prefer to be able to achieve in a formula on the cell that way I can copy-paste easily down the spreadsheet. 
If anyone has a solution or can put me on the right track would be Awesome.

Comment: You are advised to some sample data from your sheet then explain your problem and desired output based on data which will help visitor to understand your expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the formula you are looking for is :

```
your selling price (=20$) / your mark up on cost
```

where your mark up is :

```
your cost per kilo / (1- your margin)
```

So for 20% expected GP it gives :

```
= 20 / (17.5 / (1-0.2))
= 20 / 21.875
= 0.914... kilos
```

Balance is then :

```
Revenue = 20$
Cost = 0.914 * 17.5 = 16
Margin = 4
Margin % = 20
```